# Budget friendly battery charger controlled by phase angle ( SCR )

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, phase, thyristor, scr

- My circuit circuit is below so you can understand what I'm saying.
- I want to make a lead battery charger that can control the charging voltage and current (no discharge.) I have a circuit that measures both that works, so thats not a problem.
- In the circuit I posted you can see that I use a two diode full wave rectifier.  It is done with a center tapped transformer. This center tap goes to the negative terminal of the battery and the other two outputs of the transformer to the anode of the SCR. The cathodes of the SCR are connected together and go through a shunt resistor for measuring the current, then a fuse, and then to the positive terminal of the battery. (This is thought for lead batteries.)

My doubts:

1. I am measuring the current while charging. Can make the code control PWM signal for the opto  to maintain the current as if it was a "Constant Current Supply?"
   This is because I want to charge the battery in the best way possible, you know, it has a constant current charging, then a constant voltage, etc.
2. Is there a better way to achieve what I'm looking for? Better in a more budget way, without changing the base circuit? Can I improve the circuit with little changes?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: I'd like voltage&current specified. (The higher the power, the less welcome deviations from sine (and PF 1). A *battery* friendly SCR charger would have used many phases (3 at least) and a choke. This century I expect HF PFC&transformer.)

Comment: @greybeard The batteries are from 6V to 24V, and the maximum charge current is 30A. I dont know the way of doing like you said with 3 phases and a choke... Preferably i will stay with this topology, i will be reading something about what you said.

Comment: Please show the full circuit including the transformer and both battery terminals.

Comment: @Andyaka Posted!

Comment: *PWM signal from a microcontroller*: What frequency/cycle length are you aiming for?

Comment: @greybeard I will use the better one, i dont know wich, but the output of the microcontroller has a maximum about 500nS period. Based on what i should choose what frequency/period

Comment: You choose control regime based on how SCRs and lead-acid batteries work. I didn't find anything lucid on charging the latter with pulsating current. Regular SCRs can't be turned off (there used to be ("low" power) GTOs); the model I remember is *varying the time from where it could be conducting to where to trigger it*, often expressed as an angle \$\alpha\$: The bigger \$\alpha\$, the less time for conducting. For a somewhat related question see [SCR battery charger](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/590834) - note that's > 10kW max.